# Dynamic memory/realloc string array

Tags: c, arrays, memory

Looking to create a dynamic array of string values.

In the example code below, the intention was for a new array item to be added (realloc) and a new string ("string 3") to be added to the array at runtime.

I imagine the issue is either improper use of pointers and/or something wrong with the realloc logic?

Appreciate any help.

The actual output I'm getting:

```
Before: 
Array[0]: string 1
Array[1]: string 2
After: 
Array[0]: string 1
Array[1]: string 2
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **myArray;

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    myArray = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
    int arrayIndexs = sizeof(*myArray) / sizeof(char*);

    //Allocate memory for each [x]
    for (i = 0; i <= arrayIndexs; i++)
        myArray[i] = malloc(254 * sizeof(char*));
    //Populate initial values
    if(myArray != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(myArray[0], "string 1");
        strcpy(myArray[1], "string 2");
    }
    //Print out array values
    printf("Before: \n");
    for (i = 0; i <= arrayIndexs; i++)
        printf("Array[%d]: %s\n",i, myArray[i]);

    //Expand array to allow one additional item in the array
    myArray = (char **)realloc(myArray, sizeof(myArray)*sizeof(char*));

    //Allocate memory for the new string item in the array
    myArray[arrayIndexs+1] = malloc(254 * sizeof(char*));

    //Populate a new value in the array
    strcpy(myArray[arrayIndexs+1], "string 3"); //

    arrayIndexs = sizeof(*myArray)/sizeof(char*);

    //Print out array values
    printf("After: \n");
    for (i = 0; i <= arrayIndexs; i++)
        printf("Array[%d]: %s\n",i, myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *ever* find yourself attempting to use `sizeof()` for *anything* that is sized *dynamically*, you're doing it wrong. Keep that in mind. `sizeof()` is used repeatedly in this code incorrectly. Dynamic size counts must be managed by *you*; the allocation size requirements in bytes can be managed using those counts in conjunction with a `sizeof()` of the fundamental type for the item being stored.

Given that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int arrayIndexes = 2;
    char ** myArray = malloc(arrayIndexes * sizeof(*myArray));

    //Allocate memory for each [x]
    for (i = 0; i < arrayIndexes; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = malloc(254 * sizeof(char));
        sprintf(myArray[i], "string %d", i+1);
    }

    //Print out array values
    printf("Before: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < arrayIndexes; i++)
        printf("Array[%d]: %s\n", i, myArray[i]);

    // TODO: Fix this to check the result before orphaning the old
    //  value of myArray if an allocation failure ensues.
    myArray = realloc(myArray, (arrayIndexes+1) * sizeof(*myArray));
    ++arrayIndexes;

    //Allocate memory for the new string item in the array
    myArray[arrayIndexes-1] = malloc(254 * sizeof(char*));

    //Populate a new value in the array
    strcpy(myArray[arrayIndexes-1], "string 3"); //

    //Print out array values
    printf("After: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < arrayIndexes; i++)
        printf("Array[%d]: %s\n",i, myArray[i]);

    // TODO: write proper cleanup code just for good habits.
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Before: 
Array[0]: string 1
Array[1]: string 2
After: 
Array[0]: string 1
Array[1]: string 2
Array[2]: string 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You shall replace this line:

```
arrayIndexs = sizeof(*myArray)/sizeof(char*);
```

by something like this:

```
arrayIndexs += 1;
```

Reason: `sizeof` is a compile-time operator to determine the size of a datatype or datatype of an object, while here you shall manually maintain the array size.

**EDTIED:** Also when initializing the variable, you shall use

```
int arrayIndexs = 2;
```

instead of

```
int arrayIndexs = sizeof(*myArray) / sizeof(char*);
```

Comment: Thanks for the good & quick answer - much appreciated, marked WhozCraig as the best answer due to full reworked code example.